# Three beeping sound from mobo without any ram installed

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm currently debugging my new desktop that I just ordered.
I have a setup where only motherboard and CPU with a cooler installed.

When I run it, it beeps long three times. 
Upon googling I found that it is a bad ram problem, which doesn't make sense since the ram is not installed now.

My assumption is that this might be a motherboard issue.

Any suggestion/tip would be highly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: “I found that it is a bad ram problem” - yes, you haven’t put any in. That is a problem. Why are you trying to test your computer without ram? Of course it’s not going to work.

Comment: I actually laughed at this.  I know people dont know these things, but its still funny.

Comment: Well, it's like trying to drive a car without wheels. Is there no problem with wheels because there are no wheels? I think you may have been misguided by search results; they should be "bad RAM problem or no RAM installed".

Comment: Yeah, no RAM is bad.  But, besides that...  any question about the beep codes of a mobo should identify what motherboard you're talking about, because not all motherboards use the same beeps to mean the same thing.

Comment: *"...doesn't make sense..."* -- With any simple memory test, non-existent RAM versus a (catastrophic) RAM failure cannot be distinguished.  I.E. a write to any/every RAM location fails to read back correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you power on a computer, the following items must be present:

- Motherboard
- CPU
- CPU Cooler (if applicable)
- RAM
- Video card
- Power Supply Unit (obviously)

The system will not attempt a succesfull boot if any of these lack. A CPU Cooler is not necessary, but if the CPU gets too  hot, it will not start either. A wrongly seated cooler can be a reason for failure. Anyway, without RAM, the system cannot execute basic functions, and as such it will hold the system with an error.

Because the system expects RAM to be present, it says: there's bad ram, because it can't detect any. If the system thinks RAM is present (because to the system its obvious RAM is a required component), but it can't find any, then the RAM must be bad, so it displays this error rather than: "No RAM was found."

Is there anything wrong with your motherboard? No, its working as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I found online saying that when no ram is mounted, I should expect a single long beep. So I thought it is a different error from three beeps.

Comment: Actually what I've done so far is detaching one by one from a whole assembly. Since the whole assembly didn't work: it gives 4c error without booting. The error was the same until I remove the ram. (First I removed GPU, SSD, and then RAM.)

Comment: Every motherboard is different. 3 beeps or a long beep can all be error signs of missing or bad ram sticks. Refer to the manual to find out what the errorcodes mean. FYI: some motherboards have diagnostic leds instead of beeps.

Comment: Yeah I also found led solid blinking all the time... what would you recommend? I looked up the debug code/ beep code for the asrock z370, and yeah, only I found 'bad ram' about the beeping sound.

Comment: Install ram. Your motherboard is fine. Its acting exactly like it's supposed to. A pc without ram is not gonna happen.

Comment: Installing the ram gave me no beep sound. But it gave me red solid light from the bios led, and the error code '4c', which is not on the list from the ASRock website. Actually, this error code is what made me disassemble the part by part. The code showed up until I removed everything but CPU and heat sink. I was referring to this website (http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1893016/post-system-boot-video-output-troubleshooting-checklist.html) Btw, I really really appreciate your help.

Comment: Look at my list, you also need the GPU (graphics card) to be inserted. It is possible that the CPU and heatsink are not properly seated, but do note it doesn't matter what you try, if the items in the list are not present at boot, it will throw you an error in any form and it will never boot.